# ¿Por qué puedo acceder a métodos y atributos desde una subclase con this?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Espero que estén bien.

Mi pregunta puede ser algo sencilla pero no logro comprender.

Quisiera saber por qué en programación orientada a objetos puedo usar la palabra reservada `this` para acceder a los métodos y atributos de una superclase, teniendo en cuenta que usando `super` (en el caso de Java) sería mucho mas legible desde mi punto de vista.

Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo volver al manual de programación orientada a objetos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tanto `this` como `super` te ayudan a evitar ambigüedades, pero **si no vas a resolver ninguna ambigüedad no es necesario usar ninguno de los dos**.

En general no es necesario usar `this` para acceder a un atributo ni llamar a un método de la clase actual o una superclase si no da lugar ambigüedad. Ni tampoco es necesario usar `super` si no hay un método que se esté sobreescribiendo y que haya ambigüedad. (salvo en el caso de utilizar`super` para llamar al constructor de una superclase).

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Persona() {

  private Integer edad;

  public Integer getEdad() {
    return edad;
  }

  public void setEdad(Integer edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
  }

}
```

En este caso, en el método `getEdad()` no es necesario usar `this.edad` para referirse a la edad, porque no da lugar a ambigüedad. Pero en el caso del método `setEdad()` sí que hay ambigüedad, porque hay un atributo de clase y un parámetro del método con el mismo nombre.

Si no se especifica `this`, el compilador entiende que nos referimos al parámetro del método. Para referirnos al atributo, hay que precederle con un `this`, y así se evita la ambigüedad. Fíjate, que si llamásemos al parámetro con otro identificador no haría falta tampoco `this`:

```
public void setEdad(Integer edadParametro) {
  edad = edadParametro;
}
```

Por otra parte, `super` nos ayuda a evitar ambigüedades a la hora de llamar a un método que esta sobreescrito en la clase actual. Ejemplo:

```
public class Ave {

  public String ruido() {
     return "Pío pío";
  }

}

public class Pato extends Ave {

  @Override
  public String ruido() {
     return "Cuack Cuack";
  }

  public void informacion() {
     System.out.println("Soy un pato: " + ruido());
     System.out.println("También soy un ave: " + super.ruido());
     // Salida:
     // Soy un pato: Cuack Cuack
     // También soy un ave: Pío Pío
  }

}
```

En este caso, se llama a dos métodos con el nombre `ruido()`, en el primer caso, se llama al método actual que ha sido sobreescrito, y en el segundo caso, se llama al de la clase padre. Para esto es necesario `super`, ya que si no se especifica, se considera que se está llamando al método de la clase actual.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo muy claro.